# How to change the trigger of antd Collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The default trigger of [`Collapse`](https://ant.design/components/collapse/) in `antd` is clicked, but there are no provided props to change it to others such as hover.

Comment: React? Vue? Mobile? I'll make a guess you talking about React

Comment: And why you don't just use a wrapper and define `onHover` for it? Also, when asking in SO you should provide a producible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash Sorry about the incomplete question, thanks for your edition

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:hover` (CSS) or [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) event to get any desired behavior:

```
const Hover = styled(Panel)`
  :hover {
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
`;

const Text = () => (
  <div onMouseEnter={() => console.log('On Mouse Hover')}>This is Header</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Collapse onChange={callback}>
    <Hover header={<Text />} key="1">
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Hover>
  </Collapse>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[image: Edit Q-59227431-OnHover]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't get how to fold and unfold the panel with `:hover`, maybe `display: none`? But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I still don't understand the question, its incomplete. Read the links in the comments